# How do I solve $\int \frac{dx}{\sin^4(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$\int \frac{dx}{\sin^4(x)}$

I tried:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sin^4(x)} = \int \frac{dx}{(\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2})^2} = 4\int\frac{dx}{(1+\cos(2x))^2}$$

What do I do next?

Comment: Write as cosecant

Comment: @CameronWilliams I know there's a reduction formula involving the cosecant but I have no idea how to use it. Is there another way?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Higher_odd_powers_of_secant

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could continue that route, or

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^4 x}dx = \int \csc^4 x dx = \int \csc^2 x + \cot^2 x \csc^2 x \:  dx$$

then let $u = \cot x$

$$\implies -\int 1 + u^2 \: du = -u -\frac{1}{3}u^3 + C = -\cot x - \frac{1}{3}\cot^3 x + C$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\csc(x)=\frac1{\sin x}.$ Then, the integral becomes $\int \csc^4(x)dx.$ Then,

$$\int \csc^4(x)dx=\int \csc^2(x)\cdot(1+\cot^2(x)) dx=\int \csc^2(x)dx+\int\cot^2(x)\csc^2(x)dx.$$

Now, letting $\cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)},$ notice that $\frac d{dx}\cot(x)=-\csc^2(x).$ Thus, the integral above becomes:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int \csc^2(x)dx+\int\cot^2(x)\csc^2(x)dx&=-\int (\frac d{dx}\cot(x))dx-\int\cot^2(x)(\frac d{dx} \cot(x))dx\\
&=-\cot(x)-\frac{\cot^3(x)}3+C
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(I used chain rule for the last equals; $\frac{d}{dx}(\cot^3(x))=3\cot^2(x)\frac d{dx}\cot(x)$)

Comment: You were second by 4 minutes, but you were also correct and independent.